# Find a short expression for a given large integer

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, formal-languages

Give a single large number $N$, and a small set of operations and functions (in my case usually, +, -, *, ^, and $V(p,q,n),$ the nth term of  the Lucas sequence generated by $p$ and $q$), is there a clever way to find a very short expression for $N$ using these operations/functions plus small integers?   If so, I'd like to know this clever way; if not, I'd like a hint how we know there is not.

Note: In my application short means less than 72 characters, but my question is more general, so short might be *on the order of* $\,\log \log N$ characters.  Obviously we can not write every with 72 characters--but what about a given $N$?  Can we know?

**Simple Example**: given the prime 92709463146717245465044514107163, we might choose the short expression $3^{67}-2^{70}$.

**Motivation**: I run a [web site](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/home.php) which lists the largest known primes.  [Today, to make the list of the top 5000](http://primes.utm.edu/top20/trends.php) a prime must have 223,656 digits.  Most of these primes have very specific forms, most often $a\cdot b^n\pm1$, but sometimes something with more character like [the prime](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/page.php?id=105640) $$2^{810655} + 2 V(1, 2, 810653) + 1$$ (244032 digits), or [the prime](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/page.php?id=105638)  $$(121227 \cdot 2^{384976} + 3)^2 + 24398127601 \cdot 2^{384962}$$ (231,789 digits).  Occasionally folks are purposefully (or accidentally) obtuse, and try to submit the digits instead of a simple form.  Usually I can find a simple form by playing with the numbed a bit in Maple. Another time a mathematician submitted what they claimed (at the time) was "the largest known prime with no special form," a claim I did not know how to check, yet still I wondered: can I shorten this expression enough to fit on a list that only allows a 100 or so characters?

[A couple dozen new large primes](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/status.php) are submitted each day so I have tried to automate most things.  So I wonder, can the task mentioned above be automated (or at the least be sped up with mathematical insight)? Fortunately folks are rarely this obtuse and often just threatening to delete their prime is often enough for them to give me a nicer form, but sometimes they do not know of one (e.g., an ECPP record prime which makes the list by being of the 20 largest known (proven this way), even though these records are only about 10k digits).

But more than the practical question, I am just interested in the question: can we know if there is a very short form (using specified operations/functions/small integers) exists?  (What might be the shortest we can hope for?)

**A Programming question?**  Perhaps, but surely a *good* program would be guided by some mathematical principles.  There must be something better than my usual brute force method using a greedy algorithm (e.g., subtracting large terms of the form $a\cdot b^n$ and then iterating).

Perhaps I just need help phrasing the question as surely someone has asked this, I just could not find it.  I apologize in advance if I missed an obvious reference or link.

Comment: This seems similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3419/is-it-possible-to-represent-every-huge-number-in-abbreviated-form/3421#3421).

Comment: BTW thanks for maintaining your website; I have loved it for years.

Comment: Nice link @ZevChonoles, and indeed it is similar, **but** that question asked if you could "represent any and every huge random number," mine asked can you tell if you can represent a given integer N.  (And thanks @ShreevastaR).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking is a variant on the question of 'what is the simplest (shortest) description of this number?', a problem that's known to be uncomputable in general; the magic words for learning more about this are 'Kolmogorov Complexity' (and in particular, 'resource-bounded Kolmogorov complexity').  In many ways it's a sort of decryption problem (and for primes found with ECPP certificates it might even *literally* be a decryption problem), so it shouldn't be any surprise that it's hard in general.

For your particular application I think you've already hit the best short-cuts with your brute force algorithm; one particular variant on that that I would consider using would be to express the number in various bases (all $b\lt256$ or so, maybe) and look for long runs of individual base-$b$ digits, as this can help pry away terms of the form $a\cdot b^n$ and $a\cdot(b^n-1)$ even for relatively large values of $a$ (e.g., if someone discovers that $2^{513273}\cdot L(1,3,159431)+1$ is prime).  There should also be lattice-based algorithms to discover whether a given large number is of the form $L(a,b,n)$ for small $a$ and $b$, since terms of those sequences will be very (abnormally) close to simple multiples of powers of $\phi$; similar techniques might work for finding large members of other linear recurrence relations (i.e., $r_n = ar_{n-1}+br_{n-2}$), and the best starting point for finding out more about these techniques would be to have a look at the LLL (Lenstra-Lenstra-Lovász) algorithm.

Comment: Very nice answer!  I appreciate your aiming me with both the 'magic' words (so I can research the issues further) and the practical suggestions (I had not thought of looking for unusually long runs of base $b$ digits).

Comment: Minimum description length is *not* uncomputable for expression by integer arithmetic operations.  It could be NP complete, though.

Comment: @zyx Are you certain about that?  I'd be willing to bet that it's uncomputable as soon as you allow integer exponentiation, though I'll agree that 'additive-multiplicative complexity' isn't uncomputable; in binary it's probably even in NP, but I'm less certain about that (and strongly suspect it wouldn't be for a unary version of the problem).

Comment: If the size of the numbers used in the arithmetic operations is bounded (shorter, in some metric, than the integer we are trying to represent), and there is a finite menu of operations to combine them, then testing all possibilities is a finite task.  Undecidability, or a lack of known decidability, may appear if you want to know whether a number can be represented in a given form (for example, as a sum of three arbitrary 7th powers) that is allowed to utilize much larger integers.

Comment: @zyx ahh, I see what you're saying - essentially, while the numbers that could appear as a subresult of the computation could be very large, we know that the total size of all our inputs must be smaller than the original number (we have an upper bound on its complexity) and so there is a finite amount of work to consider all of the possibilities for our 'computation tree'.  (That said, the bounds this produces are absolutely horrible, and I wouldn't be surprised if there are pretty absurd - for instance, non-elementary - lower bounds on the complexity of the problem counting operation costs.

Comment: As long as every expression we're considering will compute to _some_ definite number in finitely many steps, the problem is trivially _decidable_ because we can just enumerate all expressions and check each to see if it evaluates to the target. But the link with Kolmogorov complexity is relevant all the same, because at a minimum it shows that any efficient algorithm one can find will be very sensitive to the exact operations it can handle.

Comment: @Henning: uncomputability is relatively *in*-sensitive to the exact operations allowed.  It is very sensitive to whether there is a bound on the size of the possible operands in the solution.  Computational complexity, for the decidable cases, is very sensitive to how the problem is formalized beyond naming the exact operations, such as describing how the input is measured, what sort of memory model is used and other matters.